# Memory usage cell array approach

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, cell-array

I'm having some issues with a particular piece of code (see code below). As it happens I need to get the variable Thetas. However, before the code executes I don't know how long will Thetas be or the dimensions of their matrices, since it all depends on the variable "hidden_layers".

I decided to build a blank cell array and append them as they are created for later usage. But I was wondering what would be the cheapest way to compute this. I have used the same approach many times throughout my code and I'm having some issues with memory usage.

```
% Prompt the user for how many layers will the neural network have
hidden_layers = input('How many layers on the NN?: ');

% Group of variables required to get Thetas
X = csvread('myData.csv');
n = size(X, 2);
hidden_layer_size = 60;
num_labels = 39;

% The length of Thetas{} will be => hidden_layers + 1
Thetas = {};

% Function randomize(element1, element2) returns a random matrix with
% dimensions: element2 x (element1 + 1)

% There will always be Thetas{1}
Thetas{1} = randomize(n,hidden_layer_size);

% Now build the rest of the Thetas based on the number of hidden_layers
for i = 1:(hidden_layers)
      if (i == hidden_layers)
            Thetas{i} = randomize(hidden_layer_size, num_labels);
      else
            Thetas{i} = randomize(hidden_layer_size, hidden_layer_size);
      end
end
```

PD: I've also tried to forget about the cell array and build a jx1 vector with all the Thetas appended, which I reshape later on for further computations. However, it doesn't seem to save any processing time according to the profiler and it's tiring to be reshaping it all the time.

Comment: Can you post a MCVE? we generally understand code better than explanations around here (aaah programers).

Comment: Sorry for that, you can see the code now :)